# File not found, but the file really does exist, full path given, etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text-files, discord.py

The file DOES exist, the path IS correct. I'm sure of it. Do you guys know whats going on?

Here is my code:

```
with open(f'C:\(A) Me\Coding\Python\jcjakec\Bots\storefront\storage\{user.id}Istore.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    title = lines[0]
    desc = lines[1]
    embed=discord.Embed(color=0x2f3136, description=desc, title=title)
    with open(f'C:\(A) Me\Coding\Python\jcjakec\Bots\storefront\storage\{ctx.author.id}Istoreitems.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = line.replace("\n", '')
            with open(f'C:\(A) Me\Coding\Python\jcjakec\Bots\storefront\storage\{ctx.author.id}Istore{line}', 'r') as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                name = lines[0]
                price = lines[2]
                with open(f'C:\(A) Me\Coding\Python\jcjakec\Bots\storefront\storage\{channel.guild.id}.txt', 'r') as f:
                    lines = f.readlines()
                    currencyname = lines[1]
                    embed.add_field(title=name, value=price + " " + currencyname)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jakec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\(A) Me\Coding\Python\jcjakec\Bots\storefront\sf.py", line 221, in scmd
    with open(os.path.join(f'C:\(A) Me\Coding\Python\jcjakec\Bots\storefront\storage\{ctx.author.id}Istore', line), 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\(A) Me\\Coding\\Python\\jcjakec\\Bots\\storefront\\storage\\564054910086283286Istore\\test'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jakec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\jakec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jakec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\(A) Me\\Coding\\Python\\jcjakec\\Bots\\storefront\\storage\\564054910086283286Istore\\test'
```

Hopefully you can help out!

Comment: Which line of the code you posted is line 221, because I can’t see that code in what you put in the question.

Comment: @barny its a discord bot - in progress, so the file extends much past this. I believe one of these lines is line 221.

Comment: For sure it is ok that this file has not .txt at the end?

Comment: @AlexanderGolys my god, i'm an idiot. That solved it! Sorry for wasting everyone's time - stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape backslashes (`\`) by doubling them (`\\`). They are interpreted as special characters otherwise.

Comment: Its alright, it was a stupid mistake on my part - forgot the `.txt`

Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Something easier to do is to just put an r in front of the file.
Ex -

```py
with open(r'C:\(A) Me\Coding\Python\jcjakec\Bots\storefront\storage\{user.id}Istore.txt', 'r') as f:
```